# An infinite set with the topology of enumerable complements is not compact.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite set and $\tau = \{\varnothing\} \cup \{U \subset X |\#U^c \text{ is finite or enumerable}\}$ a topology. I want to show that $(X,\tau)$ is not compact. I know that $\tau$ is a finer topology than the Zariski topology and I also know that a set with the Zariski topology is always compact, so I know that I should take a covering of $X$ with open sets that have complements which are enumerable but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: $X$ is infinite so $X$ must have a countable subset say $A$. Try creating a countable cover without a finite subcover using $A$ somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $\tau=\varnothing\cup\{U\subset X|\#U^c\text{ is finite or enumerable}\}$ I think you mean $\tau=\{\varnothing\}\cup\{U\subset X|\#U^c\text{ is finite or enumerable}\}.$

Every enumerable subset of $X$ is closed. Since $X$ is infinite, there is a set $A\subset X$ of cardinality $\aleph_0.$ With the subspace topology, $A$ is a discrete closed subspace of $X,$ and is not compact. Since a closed subspace of a compact space is compact, this shows that $X$ is not compact.